Is there a way to test a crates.io publishing pipeline without actually publishing to the production crates.io?
I'm looking to publish my first Rust package on crates. To get this right there's quite a lot of work I need to go through to setup github actions, tokens and publishing, ensuring all documentation is correctly squared away so I know how it will render on crates.io.
When I went through a similar experience in PyPi, the instructions helpfully led to publishing on https://test.pypi.org/ first. test.pypi.org is a sandbox version of https://pypi.org (akin to crates.io).  This let me fully publish a partially complete package in a safe sandbox. Sure it's publicly visible, but packages there can be short lived and deleted rapidly without causing confusion.
I absolutely do not want to "test in production" here. Cleanup on crates.io is near imposssible (discussed here)
Is there a way to fully test a crates.io publishing pipeline and see the result without actually making the package available on crates.io itself?

The problem with --dry-run is that it doesn't let me make any further downstream checks:

Ensuring everything renders as I intended when viewed through crates.io website
Ensuring the ci pipeline correctly injected the correct version number for the build
Final sanity check that pulling the published crate from another project is easily usable (no missed public).

I'm also a little unclear on the extent to which --dry-run could possibly succeed but actually publishing fail. As "all checks" inevitbly has some scope.

What exactly do you mean 'publish without making the package available?' Do you want to publish it, but not make it public? Or do you want to test that it could be published? Did you consider using --dry-run? (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-publish.html)

@Hoopra I thought I'd been really clear on that point, but extended the question to remove any ambiguity. It's not the ability to keep it secret that I need, but the ability to leave behind no junk/noise in a production space while checking the actual result of publishing.

I don't think crates.io has something equivalent.
